# Reading a text file in Python and wondering how to group specific words in specific groups

Tags: python, file

SO Im introducing my friend to Python, and Im trying to show him how to categorize words in a sentence but Im having trouble. I did something like this before which got him interested but it wasnt exactly like this, hence the fact im struggling. im trying to write a program that reads words.txt file and then calculates the sentiment of a tweet...
So the file contains words and their sentiment value...

Ex)

Sentiment Value

20

0

-10

Sentiment group

Positive

Neutral

Negative

Im trying to make a program that Reads a text file and stores the keywords into lists based on their sentiment value 
by reading each line, Splitting the line, Stripping the second element of the \n and then convert it to an int
Before grouping the first element appropriately?
Then it needs to output the lists to the console with print statements. And im using this sentence as an example

I really am very **happy** for you I **love** the weather I am also **sad** and have some **regrets** about being so **tired**

So the bold words are the keywords.

Sample output:

The positive keywords are ['love', 'happy', 'greatest']

The negative keywords are ['hate', 'hurt', 'alone', 'sad', 'regrets']

The neutral keywords are ['like', 'tired']

The sentiment of the tweet is 20

So FAR, I have (But they both seem very wrong?!)

```
keywords = open("keywords.txt", "w")

keywords.write()

keywords = open("keywords.txt", "r")

sentVal = (line.split(',') for line in keywords.readlines())

line = keywords.readline()

for line in keywords:      
     line = line.rstrip()
     print(keywords)
```

and I also tried

```
keywords = [20, 0, 10]    
sentimentGroup = ["positive", "neutral", "negative"]
tweet = open(keywords.txt, "r")
tweets = sentimentGroup.readline
tweets_list = tweet.split("\n")
len(tweets_list)

for tweet in tweets_list[0:5]:
  print(tweet)

tweets.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like that:

```
from collections import Counter

positive = {'love', 'happy', 'greatest'}
negative = {'hate', 'hurt', 'alone', 'sad', 'regrets'}
neutral = {'like', 'tired'}

def sentiment_of_msg(msg_words_counter):
    summary = 0
    for key, quantity in msg_words_counter.items():
        if key in positive:
            summary += 20 * quantity
        elif key in negative:
            summary += -10 * quantity
    return summary


tweet_filename = 'tweets.txt'
with open(tweet_filename, 'r') as fp:
    for line in fp.readlines():
        ct = Counter(line.split())
        s = set(ct)
        pos, neu, neg = s & positive, s & neutral, s & negative
        print('The positive keywords are: {}'.format(', '.join(pos)))
        print('The neutral keywords are: {}'.format(', '.join(neu)))
        print('The negative keywords are: {}'.format(', '.join(neg)))
        sentiment = sentiment_of_msg(ct)
        print('The sentiment of tweet is {}'.format(sentiment))
```

Example output for your `line = '''I really am very happy for you I love the weather I am also sad and have some regrets about being so tired'''`
 line would look like:

```
The positive keywords are: love, happy
The neutral keywords are: tired
The negative keywords are: regrets, sad
The sentiment of tweet is 20
```

It might not be the best way to do it, but it should work.

Comment: Okay it runs with no errors, but how do I get it to check the line? do I just add line = '''I really am very happy for you I love the weather I am also sad and have some regrets about being so tired''' somewhere?

Comment: I assumed that you are having those lines in file with `tweet_filename`, so the file is being opened, and then, read line by line.

Answer (score 0):

Try using dictionaries. Each value will have a key and value of either negative, positive or neutral.

```
words = {"sad": -5, "happy": 5, "ok": 0, "joyful": 10, "angry": -10}
# like above - is negitive words, + is positive words and netrual is netrual words. 
value = ""
for w in f.read().split(): # 'f' is a file object
  if w.lower() in words:
    value += str(words[w.lower()]) + " + "
print(value.strip(" + ")) # I use python3, you can get rid of the parenthese if you want.
```

If the file input is like this,

```
I am happy
You are sad
They are doing ok but sometimes they are angry
You and I are joyful
```

Then the output of this with the file object as this file will be, `5 + -5 + 0 + -10 + 10`